# Broken ux(cards) in skype

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to build my own bot and I am using c#(vs2017). My bot works perfectly in my emulator and it works even in test panel after publishing it to azure. In skype it got published successfully but I get a broken card with two lines displayed. I am trying to display a herocard with 6-7 lines of text.

Do we have a limit of no of words??

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you clarify your question do you mean "Do we have a limit of number  of words??"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the text is limited. Skype is more variable than say Messenger, which has a documented hard limit: the amount of text shown by Skype varies on whether you have a title and/or subtitle or neither.

Back when I ran some tests on Skype I found a limit was around 200 characters, if there was no title or subtitle.

You may be able to get more by not having an image. I didn't test that.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the quick response.this was the reason. when i removed title and subtitle the text got diplayed for few.is there any way to display more than 200 characters using cards?even if i remove image the text is not getting displayed completely.@stuartd

Comment: No, you are limited by what the channel allows.